# Does it satisfy functional principle?

Tags: scala

I am new in Scala and wrote following code:

```
  def createProps(host: String)(config: List[KkConfig]): Eval[Properties] = {

    val evalProps = Foldable[List].foldRight(config, Later(new Properties())) {
      (a: KkConfig, b: Eval[Properties]) =>
        a match {
          case ClientId(value: String) =>
            b.map((p: Properties) => {
              p.put(ProducerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, value)
              p
            })
          case Acks(value: String) =>
            b.map((p: Properties) => {
              p.put(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, value)
              p
            })
          case Retries(value) =>
            b.map((p: Properties) => {
              p.put(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, value)
              p
            })
          case BatchSize(value) =>
            b.map((p: Properties) => {
              p.put(ProducerConfig.BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG, value)
              p
            })
          case LingerMs(value) =>
            b.map((p: Properties) => {
              p.put(ProducerConfig.LINGER_MS_CONFIG, value)
              p
            })
          case BufferMemory(value) =>
            b.map((p: Properties) => {
              p.put(ProducerConfig.BUFFER_MEMORY_CONFIG, value)
              p
            })

        }
    }

    evalProps
      .map(p => {
        p.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, host)
        p
      })
      .map(p => {
        p.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer")
        p
      })
      .map(p => {
        p.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer")
        p
      })
  }
```

What makes me confuse is the `new Properties()` object. With every recursive call `foldRight`, I insert a new key and value into `Properties` object, I change the object every time.

```
p.put(ProducerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, value)
```

I want to know, if it is functional or not, because I put something into object with every recursive call.

Comment: Where do you see recursion here? `foldRight`? That's not necessarily implemented using a recursive call. To be honest, this seems like an overkill just to create a `Properties` object.

Comment: How would you improve the code?

Comment: `foldRight` is recursive, that is what I mean.

Comment: You are filling in the `Properties` object with a new property each time. Not sure I understand your question.

Comment: Yes and Properties keep always the state. It does not produce a new state. In my opinion, it is not pure.

Comment: That's because `Properties` is mutable, and there's nothing you can do about that. What you can do is fill an immutable map: `Map[String, AnyRef]`, and then once you're done pass it to the `Properties` constructor.

Comment: There is a properties constructor with map?

Comment: Hmm, I seem to be mistaken. But there is `Properties.enumerate` which you can pass a `HashTable` to.